# How do I close Libre Office when closing a document? (default settings for LXSession)

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, lxsession

I use Lubuntu 16.04 and Libre Office Version: 5.1.6.2.

When I work on a text document and then save and close it, libre office shows the main screen where I can choose between different documents and create a new one.

I don't want that.

When closing a document I want the whole application to close.

How can I set this up?

EDIT: I open up the document by clicking on it. LXSession default for 'document' is already 'Libre Office Writer'. It seems that LXSession default opens up Libre Office as a whole instead of just the writer.

Comment: Open LO  Writer directly instead of opening the "loader" (or whatever it is called).

Comment: You are right. It works the way you suggest. But I open the document via clicking on it, not via opening up the writer and then opening a document from within the writer. In 'LXSession configuration' under 'launching applications' I have 'Libre Office Writer' as default. So it seems to be a problem with the default settings.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Huh?!? How could I do that? What I had to say is there, that's it, nothing else to add and I don't even know the correct name of the "thing". And this is so obvious...

Comment: His answer is nice but does not solve the problem, as I clearly stated in my comment and edit to thw question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved (sort of) this very same issue just by unticking the  'LibreOffice' menu item from Lubuntu's Main Menu dialog.

Hope this helps.
(This should be a comment, but I'm not allowed by my reputation)

Comment: It doesn't have to be a comment. You are allowed to answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a copy paste answer from [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/can-i-supress-the-images-on-the-start-screen/7528/3)

In LibreOffice 5.2 or later you can use Tools|Options → LibreOffice → Advanced → Open Expert Configuration to switch thumbnail mode. Search for RecentDocsThumbnail property and toggle the value to false.

See below for the initial answer with alternative ways and workaround for older versions of LibreOffice.